# Relative link not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project and I'm using bootstrap. I'm configuring a nav bar. This is the code for one item in my nav bar.

```
<li class="active"><a href="/aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
```

When I load the index.html instead of pointing it at '**C:/Users/.../about.html**' it's pointing at '**file:///C:/aboutus.html**'. Obviously, I'm getting an error 404 here.

Now when I change the code to:

```
<li class="active"><a href="../project/aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
```

It's now pointing to the right location and I'm able to access the page.

What is happening?

Edit: Yes, I'm running it locally. The same is happening to every file here and in rest of the file system. The file tree is:

```
../project/aboutus.html
../project/index.html
../project/css/<contains standard bootstrap files>
../project/fonts/<contains standard bootstrap files>
../project/js/<contains standard bootstrap files>
```

Edit2: It's also working fine if I just add a single dot before the relative path. Like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="./aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
```

Comment: Could you post a little information about what your file tree looks like? Also, it sounds like you're just running this off your local machine without a server, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Links beginning with a "/" are absolute paths. In your case you should remove it.
Try with :

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a>
</li>
```

Comment: "Links beginning with a "/" are absolute links" — They are absolute paths and relative URLs. "Absolute link" is not a term with any standard meaning.

Comment: It's working. But I'm a little confused here. Here: [link](http://www.navegabem.com/linking-strategy.html) it's written that 'A relative link will look like this: <a href="/index.html">Home</a>'. So am I not using the relative link here?

Comment: @SaifAlFalah I'm not certain enough of this to put it in an answer, but I _think_ that what's going on is that it's relative to the home path, which in this case is `C:/`. It's sort of a weird case, because usually one would be serving these files off of a server, not your hard drive

Comment: `/` reflects to home of directory. and therefore it was locating file:///C:/aboutus.html than the correct one. Skipping `/` would work.

Comment: @svangordon yeah. I guess you're right. But what's even weirder is that it was working fine before but then suddenly, it started throwing errors. I've also cleared my cache, used a different browser, checked on different computers etc. but it just doesn't work.

Comment: @VisvendraKarnawat thank you for your reply. It's working without `/` but I swear it was working with that before. Just suddenly, it stopped.

Comment: @SaifAlFalah Were you running this index.html in any server? Like if you run this index.html in bracket IDE then it would run with `/` also because bracket IDE provides its own server.

Comment: @VisvendraKarnawat bingo! I was running it on brackets' server. Thank you so much!